# Android Fatal Signal 11 from XML

Tags: android, image, runtime

I am creating an Android app and I have yet to run out of memory until just now.  The part that is confusing is it was not a way I would expect to run out of memory.

I simply added a new Linear Layout to a layout xml file.  It had a background of an image that was 40kb large.  The other images that were loaded were approximately 12kb with the background being much larger at 120kb.  When this image was loaded I would receive a Fatal Signal 11 on runtime.  If I removed the background from the layout it would work fine.  I then changed the image to be much smaller, it was (2000x600) before so now it is 14kb.  It now works fine.  It is clear that the extra 26kb was causing a problem...

What kind of precautions should I take to ensure this doesn't happen again.  Obviously I would like quality images and the 2000x600 might be excessive as it's an app for a phone but what guidelines should I follow?

Is there a memory usage cap that can be extended or that I should look to stay under?  Also, if I loaded many images on a scrollview will this cause the app to crash?  I have had many images loaded at once but have never had it crash before, I'm just confused as to the error being caused by very little memory usage.  (In todays terms at least.)

Regards,

Jake

Answer (score 0):

Images do not consume the same amount of memory in RAM as they do on disk. You can get the RAM usage by:

```
width*height*4 (for images with an alpha channel)
```

and

```
width*height*3 (for images without an alpha channel)
```

An Android app is allotted a definite amount of heap space in the RAM, which will always be the same on a particular device and ROM version on that device. The minimum is 16 MB, though these days most devices give you a more comfortable 32 MB or 64 MB. It really depends on the device.

You get `Out of Memory Exceptions` (OOMs) when your app exceeds this heap space. The simple fix is: Don't exceed this heap space.

The best way to get quality images in your app is to use the density buckets and provide different sizes from which Android can choose. LDPI screens cannot make use of high res images anyways, so you should only supply a low res on in LDPI. On the other hand, HDPI devices can make use of better resolution, and if you supply one Android can use it. It is almost a given that the higher the resolution of the device, the more heap space you will be allotted for the running of your app.

Another way to manage memory is to only load what you need, by implementing lazy loading. This is especially helpful with listviews and scrollviews and other adapter based View systems.

On Android 3.0 and above, you can request a bigger heap by using `android:largeHeap="true"`. However, this should be avoided as the user will notice other apps of theirs being removed from memory whenever your app is launched, and it is not guaranteed that you will receive a larger heap in any case.

Comment: I am getting my percentage of usage for the app I'm running through runtime.getRuntime().getFreeMemory, etc... It's around 75%.  I found that when I would clear the cache or remove the background image of the app it would actually take up more memory, even if it was in small amounts like 4kb or so.. should the app take up that much?